# I am new to Ubuntu. I have pre-installed standard Ubuntu 22.04 lts. l want to change to Ubuntu studio 22.04 lts. do I download & reinstall or upgrade

Tags: upgrade, system-installation, downloads

I have pre-installed Ubuntu 22.04 lts standard. Want to change to Ubuntu studio 22.04. Do I upgrade  or download studio 22.04 and reinstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to do both.

You could install individual software packages. They should work in your current desktop. Some desktops may see some lagging/skipping if you are not using Ubuntu Studio's low-latency kernel (which you can also install).

You could install the `ubuntustudio-desktop` package, which will install the entire Ubuntu Studio environment. You switch between kernels at GRUB and between environments at the login screen. There is a bit of complexity trying to juggle two desktop environments, so we don't recommend it for beginners. Users with intermediate experience of package management should have no problems.

You can wipe your current system and install Ubuntu Studio. This is the path that is easiest for most beginners.

**Note**: Ubuntu Studio 22.04 is supported for 3 years (April 2025). That's different from Ubuntu Desktop, which is supported for 5 years (April 2027).